# How do i append a value to an armadillo matrix?

Tags: c++11, armadillo

I have an iterator that iterates through a vector and I need to append values into an armadillo matrix. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: plz add some code so ppl can understand and see what are you trying to accomplish.
What type of objects does your matrix / vector holds ? what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
insert_rows(row_number, X)
insert_cols(col_number, X)
```

depending on how you are adding elements. Ideally, you should define the size of your matrix at declaration, and iterate through your matrix using element access, i.e.:

```
[],
(), or
.at()
```

Comment: using `X.insert_rows(...)` or `X.insert_cols(...)` to append single elements should be avoided -- it's inefficient.